# How to provide fixed 'key values' within a class?

Tags: c#

I'm new to C#, and this is a very simple question, but as I can't figure out the right terminology for what I'm looking for, I'm struggling to google this for the simple answer.

I'd like the user of a class to be able to retrieve certain fixed values by name from within the class. As below:

```
byte mode = MyClass.Modes.ModeC;
```

Where ModeC is a specific value of byte that the user will need to use.

I've seen this used everywhere, but I can't figure out what the best way to implement it is.

I've tried:

```
public class MyClass
{
    public class Modes
    {
        public static byte ModeA = 0x01;
        public static byte ModeB = 0x03;
        public static byte ModeC = 0x06;
        //etc
    }
}
```

It seems to work.
Is this a sensible way to achieve this? What is this practice called?

Sorry for the very obvious question, but I'd appreciate any help I could get!

Comment: Enums? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.enum?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: You implementation allows for users of the class to modify the values - to avoid this you could declare the values as const rather than static. Or as @WashingtonA.Ramos has suggested you can use enums (you can define the enum value type as byte)

Comment: Your current declaration allows _anyone_ to modify the value of `Modes.ModeA` (and the others). It seems like your'e looking either for an `enum`, rather than a `class`, or possibly for `const` instead of `static`. `static readonly` is _also_ a thing, which, pragmatically, is similar to `const` but allows the value to be set at run-time rather than compile time.

Comment: Are you looking for a [dictionary](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.dictionary-2?view=netframework-4.8) of bytes indexed by strings? (Since you are saying "retrieve *by name*", which to me sounds like a string.) Instead of writing 256 values manually you can probably use byte.ToString() in a loop...

Comment: No I really was just forgetting the word enum... Evidence of which is now forever on the internet :( Not looking for a dictionary in this case, but thank you

Comment: @JRVeale That's ok ;-). The next person in the same situation may find this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
using System;

class MainClass {
  public static void Main (string[] args) {
    Console.WriteLine ("Value of " + Modes.ModeC + " is " + (byte)Modes.ModeC);
  }

  public enum Modes : byte {

    ModeA = 0x01,
    ModeB = 0x03,
    ModeC = 0x05

  }
}
```

Comment: Yes, thank you! I've been away from programming for a while, but I still can't believe I forgot about enums. What a brain fart!

Comment: This becomes cumbersome for the consumer of your class though. You will always have to be casting it to byte. For instance "byte myMode = MyClass.Modes.ModeA;" will create a compilation error regarding being unable to implicitly cast.

Comment: OP's original method is more correct (though it should be declared as a const). It allows the user to get the value from the class without having to instantiate it and it allows the consumer of his class to directly assign it to a byte type variable. The enum would only be useful in your case if you're using it directly as an enum in my opinion (meaning you don't specifically need the values from it).

Comment: @JoshMaag  It is only "cumbersome" if you decide to assign to a byte - if you are not concerned about the actual value - then assigning to a Modes enum (or using var)  would be the correct way to go.

Comment: @JoshMaag, all functions the user will need to use the byte for would be written to take a `Modes` as a parameter rather than a byte. The user should rarely care what the underlying real byte value is.

Comment: This answer would greatly benefit from an explanation of the code beyond "this".

Answer (score 1):

One easy way can be using a static class with public const values.

```
public static class ApplicationConsts
{
    public const byte ModeA = 0x01;
    public const byte ModeB = 0x03;
    public const byte ModeC = 0x06;
}
```

Then you would be able to use it as

```
var modeA = ApplicationConsts.ModeA;
```